# Protobuf-2.6.0 with Python 3?

Tags: python, protocol-buffers, python-3.4

In the [release notes of Google's Protocol Buffer v2.6.0](https://github.com/google/protobuf/blob/master/CHANGES.txt#L61), it says there is now support for Python 3. However, when I try `pip install protobuf`, I still get an error because the setup.py file is still written in Python 2 (it fails on line 79: `except pkg_resources.VersionConflict, e:`).

Anyone been able to get it to work with Python 3? I'm using Python 3 within a virtualenv.

Comment: [2to3 - Automated Python 2 to 3 code translation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/2to3.html)?

Comment: Doesn't work for me either. File a bug.

Comment: Thanks, @simonzack. Looks like a couple of people beat me to it on Github.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Google acknowledges it is not actually fully compatible with Python 3 yet on [this bug ticket](https://github.com/google/protobuf/issues/9). If anyone wants to try 2to3 beforehand, they list the files you would need to run through to get it to work on [this related ticket](https://github.com/google/protobuf/issues/7).